# jQuery iterations with validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I have about 40 questions in a survey that need to be validated all the same way.  What's the easiest way to do this without writing every validation down?

For example: Every question must be a natural number, maxlength of 2, and value less than 12.

*Using [jQuery validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)*

Comment: Please define "validation".  Do you mean "every question has to be answered" or "answers must text strings less than 80 chars long" or "answers must come from a finite list of possibilities"?

Comment: Sorry, I've been away.  How do I use any of the code below in conjunction with jQuery validation plugin?  I'm a bit confused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without any details on your code - something like this could be a starting point:

```
$('.class-of-your-validation-elements').each(function() { your_validation_code($(this)); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any code it is hard to help. Most likely a `for` loop will do or jQuery's [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method.

Or maybe the [jQuery Validation PLugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to all the validators, then in your loading function, attach the validation function, e.g.

```
function validationFunction(e)
{
    $(this).val() > 5;
}

$(function() {
    $('.validators').bind('blur', validationFunction);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily ad an onsubmit method to your form, like this:

```
$().ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {//adds a javascript check to the form's submit
         $('form input').each(function() {//this loops through each input in the form
              var inputValue = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
              if (inputValue < 12) { hideErrors();}
              else { displayErrors(); return false;}
         });
    });
```

});

Hope this helps.

the validation plugin mainly works when you add classes to existing inputs, my above method will loop through any inputs in the form without a need to add classes to all of the inputs